# Dictionary parameter only initialised on first call to function

Tags: python

I have a directory walker that I invoke in a loop for specified directories:

```
fileDataBySize = walkDirectory( directoryToProcess, ... )
```

The walker then invokes itself recursively, collecting the file data, and returning it when done:

```
def walkDirectory(path, fileDataBySize=dict(), ...): 
    ...
    if ...:
        fileDataBySize = walkDirectory( subpath, fileDataBySize, ... )
    ...
    return fileDataBySize
```

The `fileDataBySize` dictionary clearly needs to be reinitialised at the start of each top level invocation of `walkDirectory()`, but whilst the code outlined above initialises it fine on the first call, it then manages to retain the contents for subsequent top level invocations.

Obviously this is easy to fix, but I'm wondering how this is being done, and what I've missed in my understanding of the language.

Comment: Values (actually expressions) of default parameters are evaluated once when the function is defined, not when it is called.

Comment: @MichaelButscher  That explains it.  Many thanks!